# What is it called when 2/2 is imposed in 3/4?

Tags: theory, time-signatures

What is the name in music theory for when the feel of 2/2 is imposed in 3/4 time? For example in Waltz No. 2 by Shoshtakovich (i think its that one) there is a section about midway through where its 3/4, but the melody plays half notes for about 6 measures or so. Im not sure how exactly to explain it.

Comment: Other famous examples is Mozart's minuet in symphony 40, Bernstein's _America_ from _West Side Story_.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I don't see it in the minuet of Mozart's Symphony 40. One notable extended hemiola is in the finale of Schumann's piano concerto.

Comment: @RosieF, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._40_(Mozart) scroll down to the minuet description. After the anacrusis the first two bars use the hemiola.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about *hemiola* a combination of a 2 pattern and a 3 pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiola

Using accent marks `>` in 3/4 it would be like...

```
      >   >     >      >   >      >
3/4 | / / / | / / /  | / / /  | / / / |
```

The hemiola effect can be realized in a score in a variety of ways:

- accents like in my example above
- the use of beaming in multiples of 2 against a meter of 3
- simply changing chords on the pattern of 2 in a meter of 3 is enough to make hemiola felt

However the effect is created the meter of 3 needs to established as the base from which the pattern of 2 conflicts. For example, you would need to accent in 3's first to establish the 3/4 meter then shift temporarily to a pattern of accents in 2's. Or, you would need to *simultaneously* play accents in 2's and 3's. This pattern conflict is essential for hemiola. If the music doesn't have a proper hemiola treatment it could simply sound like a meter change.

Comment: Is “syncopation” a synonym or is there a difference between them that I don’t know?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - A hemiola is a specific type of syncopation. Syncopation can easily happen in 4/4 time, for instance, while hemiolas won't.